# ssh X11 forwarding from multiple clients simultaneously always opens openoffice windows on the same screen - bug or feature?

Tags: ssh, openoffice

## Situation:

Three "computers":

A. a desktop with its own display
B. a virtual machine on A (kvm)
C. a small PC with its own display

I generally work on A, `ssh -Y` to B from A, work with `firefox --no-remote` & `openoffice` started in B (in the `ssh` bash shell), displayed on A's display.

So far so good.

## New requirement:

I now logged in to C, `ssh -Y` to A, and from there `ssh -Y` to B, so that my daughter can work at the same time as I on this same VM.

I use `openoffice` to work on a document on B, displayed on C's display (from within the double `ssh -Y`).

## Problem:

Any attempt to open an `openoffice` window whether in the `ssh` shell started on A, or even in the `virt-manager`/`virt-viewer` window (i.e. directly in the VM), will open its window on C's display!

I tried `xeyes` and it opens where expected.

So it must be some `openoffice` magic at work.

## Question:

How do I turn this magic off?

Comment: Do you both use the same user on B? Then I guess it's the same `openoffice`. New instance delegates its task to the already running one and dies; the old one uses its old `DISPLAY` variable. I don't know `openoffice` but technically once started it may even keep its main process running without any window to speed up opening documents in the future. If you kill it and start anew, it will start with new `DISPLAY` value, but the other person will not be able to use `openoffice` on their display. Use separate users on B. Not an answer because I'm not sure. Please investigate.

Comment: Yes, same user. When I close `openoffice` on C, then I can open it on A. But while open on C, I can only open new windows on C. Is there  no way to open independent sessions with the same user?

Answer (score 1):

In libreoffice you can do something like this:

```
 libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/test
```

and it will open a new instance for the same user. It's a bit like the --no-remote you are using in Firefox.

The idea is to state that for this execution, the environment is not what it usually is and thus force a new instance to deal with it.

No idea if that will work in OpenOffice though, but since they are very similar, you could use libreoffice just for that situation.

Comment: Thanks, a good tip, unfortunately I can only have `openoffice` on this old VM, and it does not seem to have a similar feature. Also to note that the `--no-remote` in `firefox` has a very different purpose and effect: by default if `firefox` exists on the client, it is that version that gets started by the remote shell. `--no-remote` ensures that the version that gets started is the one on the target side of the `ssh -Y` command. And it is only possible to start a `--no-remote` session if the target host and user is not already running `firefox`.

Comment: in Firefox "--no-remote" implies "--new-instance". And it's indeed possible to start a --no-remote/--new-instance if the user is already running firefox and the target host is the same. Just try it, I do it all the time, for testing, same user, same host, different profile (if you look at it, the -env solution for libreoffice is actually changing the environment in a way that resembles what Firefox does with the profile. But you do not have to agree on the likeness.

Comment: I just checked starting a second instance of `firefox --no-remote` and the error message is pretty clear: "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system". Both on Ubuntu 10.04 (firefox 20.0) and Ubuntu 18.04 (firefox 69.0.1).

Comment: Same with  `firefox --new-instance`!

Comment: Maybe you missed the "different profile" part.

Comment: Indeed, I had assumed `--new-instance` was sufficient.